# How to round to the nearest 0.05?

Tags: java, rounding

I'm trying to find a way on how to round to the nearest 0.05 in java. Let's say that I have the following numbers:

```
0.33
0.02
0.874
0.876
```

This should become:

```
0.35
0.00
0.85
0.90
```

I tried many things and I can only get it to round to n places behind the comma by using `BigDecimal`, but I can't seem to find a way for this one.

Can someone help me?

EDIT: Thank you for all your help, I am amazed at how easy this could be done. And how do I get the double converted into a string properly? I can't use `Double.toString(double d)` because for example the string will be `"0.9"` instead of `"0.90"`?

Comment: Do you need it rounded and stored as a number, or just displayed as string?  I know you can format strings with a specific number of decimal places, but I'm not sure off hand how to do it as a number.

Comment: multiply by 20, round, divide by 20,  works out to the same number

Comment: And how can the double be properly formatted to a string, like explained above?

Answer (score 4):

0.05 == 1/20, right? Therefore, what you need is just the nearest number with dividing by 1/20, so, you may multiply this number by 20, get the nearest number with dividing by 1, then get the initial things.

TL;DR: you just may just multiply it by 20, round and divide by 20 again:

```
public double customRound(double num) {
    return Math.round(num * 20) / 20.0;
}
```

Comment: And how can the double be properly formatted to a string, like explained above?

Comment: @n00b1990 For example, `String.format("%.2f", customRound(num));`

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be:

```
double d = 0.33;
double roundedTimes20 = Math.round(d * 20);
double rounded = roundedTimes20 / 20; //0.35
```

but note that the resulting double is not necessarily the exact representation of the rounded number (usual floating point caveat) and that the method ***assumes that your original double times 20 can fit in a long***.

Comment: And how can the double be properly formatted to a string, like explained aboive?

Comment: You can use a DecimalFormat - see the question linked as duplicate or search a bit on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try a function:

```
    public static double round05(double num) {
            return Math.round(num * 20) / 20.0;
    }
```

Comment: And how can the double be properly formatted to a string, like explained above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.format to format value to String

```
String s = String.format("%.2f", 0.9);
```